# Multiple labels with different names in a frame for python

Tags: python

I am new in python and a need to have in my solution multiple labels. My solution was below. Somebody has a better solution for this? I need 20 labels.

```
            if pos_x == 1:
                lb1 = Label(janela, text=data[rabo], font="arial 18")
                lb1.grid(row=pos_x, column=pos_y, padx=2, pady=2)
            if pos_x == 2:
                lb2 = Label(janela, text=data[rabo], font="arial 18")
                lb2.grid(row=pos_x, column=pos_y, padx=2, pady=2)
            if pos_x == 3:
                lb3 = Label(janela, text=data[rabo], font="arial 18")
                lb3.grid(row=pos_x, column=pos_y, padx=2, pady=2)
            if pos_x == 4:
                lb4 = Label(janela, text=data[rabo], font="arial 18")
                lb4.grid(row=pos_x, column=pos_y, padx=2, pady=2)
            if pos_x == 5:
                lb5 = Label(janela, text=data[rabo], font="arial 18")
                lb5.grid(row=pos_x, column=Pos_y, padx=2, pady=2)
```

Comment: Use a loop and a list.

Comment: Why are you giving all the labels different variable names?, you should also be using `elif` but really theres no need for any of these if statements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
if pos_x == i:
    lb[i] = Label(janela, text=data[rabo], font="arial 18")              
    lb[i].grid(row=pos_x, column=pos_y, padx=2, pady=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `lb1`,...,`lb5` (up to `lb20`) is looking strange to me. They are almost (?) identical, so I would suggest to use a list:

```
lb = [None] * number_of_lb  # make array of 20 None
...
lb[pos_x] = Label(..)
lb[pos_x].grid = ...
```

Later you can access them as `lb[0]`, `lb[1]`, etc.